# Why I am Getting All Records with reply when get Data from Sharepoint Discussion board using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, discussion-board

I am trying to get all question from `Discussion board list` using `REST API`.

Now, what problem I am faced.

1. I am fetching Only question but I am getting replay also inside response.
2. And how can I decide which is Reply or Question and If Its reply then which question reply it is.?

My Query Like below:

```
https://demo.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/lists/getbytitle('Files%20Discussionboard')/items?$select=ID,Title,ContentTypeId,Body,Created,FileOwner/FirstName1,FileOwner/LastName,Folder/ItemCount,Folder/Title&$expand=FileOwner,Folder
```

Any help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Post the query you have tried so far

Comment: @AmalHashim i have posted My REST Query

Comment: did you want it as all questions or all discussion topics in the discussion list?

Comment: I want all Question with additional column data. and from particular question i have to retrieve its replays  if it have

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/JS/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getData, "sp.js");

});


function getData()
{
    var string = "";

     jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://YOURDOMAIN/sites/SITE_NAME/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Discussions List')/items", //THE ENDPOINT
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: { 
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
                        "IF-MATCH": "*",  
                        "X-HTTP-Method": null
            },
            success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){

                        string += item.Title;
                    });
                    alert(string);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                    alert('Error getListItems :: '+JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: i think its give you all records of list with reply records but i want main Question records. not reply .

Comment: Yes this code is giving you only the topics of discussion and not the replies. Try implementing it.

Comment: i have already tried.see  i have posted url for this call In myquestion. i am getting record of replays also

Comment: But I am not getting replies by using this code I have also tried my code. I am only getting the topics of discussion.There is a difference in your URL and in my URL.

Comment: I am just write query in url.before it fetching url are same brother. have you give reply  inside discussion board? first give rply then check.

Comment: Have given a reply in discussion

Comment: then whats mistake i have did. can you telll me. is my query wrong?